# get longitude and latitude in EPSG:32750

Tags: mapinfo

I have mapinfo file and spatial type is point. I want to know longitude and latitude but in this file not include field to specific describe to longitude and latitude. 
the `CRS` is `WGS 84/UTM zone 50s (EPSG:32750)`. I have to export the file `(.tab)` using ogr but the result is not like a longitude and latitude.

*this is the result:*

```
POINT (238339.99924633466 9640080.0006718487)
POINT (238540.00219973351 9640080.0006718487)
POINT (238559.99837215125 9640080.0006718487)
POINT (238580.0027904133 9640080.0006718487)
```

If I want to get the longitude & latitude from this file is posible?how can?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run those points through a conversion to get a "normal" (cartesian) latitude and longitude coordinates from them. [OSGeo.org](http://www.osgeo.org) has several libraries available to convert these points and translate them to global latitude and longitude points. [FreeGIS.org](http://freegis.org/database/?cat=0) also has a list of tools that you can sort by language. I believe that "Geo" people prefer to use longitude, latitude when describing points. 
    POINT( longitude latitude )